# Starting WinAppDriver.exe programmatically

Tags: java, windows, winappdriver

Before starting test execution, I have to manually start this WinAppDriver.exe.

I want to automate this task when I start executing my test cases it should start this exe and after finish it will close it.

I have tried in Java with below code but I'm not success:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();

String executablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Application Driver\\WinAppDriver.exe";

Process process = runTime.exec(executablePath);
```

Note: I required to run it with 'Run As Administrator'

Comment: I have done this in a C# project. If you like, I can post it in a answer.
Try running your tests with a user who has sufficient privileges to prevent that 'Run As Administrator' window, or try running your IDE as a user with admin privileges.

Comment: Or did you mean that clicking the "Run As Adminsitrator" window has to be a part of your test script?

Comment: I want to run this driver EXE by code instead of doing it manually. I want java code fix, and this exe required to run as Administrator. I have user with admin privileges,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using ProcessBuilder class from java as is it recommended to use it after Java 5 for starting/creating processes. Below code will start the WinAppDriver.exe :

```
String command = "C:\Users\Administrator\WinAppDriver\WinAppDriverTool\WinAppDriver.exe";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();
startWinAppDriver = builder.start();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both worked for me without staring eclipse as Admin .

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Application Driver\\WinAppDriver.exe");
```

Also the Sukhangad singh's answer.

```
 String command = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Application Driver\\WinAppDriver.exe";
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();
    builder.start();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I need to run it on a different port like 8888 or on a different Ip.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct but if you want to run winapp driver on specific ports then in that case you will need to use this

```
   String command = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Application Driver\\WinAppDriver.exe";
                List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
                commands.add(command);
                commands.add("8888");
                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands).inheritIO();
                Process p=builder.start();
                p.destroy();
```

Here we can pass all parameters inside the list and pass this list object inside ProcessBuilder.

Default URL: http://127.0.0.1:4723

In our case URL:http://127.0.0.1:8888